# IDEA - after importing maven project, can't see source code

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

Got a new pc, and trying to import an existing maven project into **IDEA** *(version 2018.3)*, with following steps:

`import` -> `import project from external model` -> `maven`

But, after importing, there is no `src` dir, I have tried many times, each time delete `.idea/` before re-import.

I remember it did work before, but not this time.

And, I can compile the project successfully with `mvn compile`, also `Eclipse` could import it correctly.

Any idea what's wrong, and how to fix it?

Comment: Did you try to import it as a regular java project? If no, what happens if you do so?

Comment: be sure to select the pom.xml file when you import the project.

Comment: When I import a pom.xml I get the standard Maven directory structure.  If you already have source code, you might try creating the project from existing sources and simply using the pom.xml.

Comment: @gazzo Seems result is the same despite whether selecting the project dir or the pom.xml.

Comment: Works fine in my IntelliJ 2018.3.  I don't know what you're doing wrong.

Comment: @lealceldeiro I have tried almost every provided way to import, the `src` dir just won't show ...

Comment: @EricWang what happens if you import with file -> new -> project from existing sources?

Comment: Sure you're looking at the project view in the left panel?

Comment: @gazzo I just tried both way on another machine with `IDEA 2019.1` on the same maven project, both succeed. That machine is not at hand now, I will try it tomorrow again.

Comment: @duffymo Yes, `Alt + 1` opened the project view.

Comment: @gazzo On the pc `IDEA 2019.1` works for the same project dir, while `IDEA 2018.3.2` still can't see the `src` dir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check if your intelliJ is collecting POM dependencies, on large projects it can go for hours. During collecting dependencies you will see no folders, but only root files.

If the above is not the case, right click on `white project area/Maven/Reimport`.

If you don't see it or that doesn't fix the problem, go to `File->Project Structure...` then choose `Modules` and check if you have duplicated modules and remove them.

Comment: Just tried,  after right click there is no `Maven` options, seems it's not recognized as maven project, weird.

Comment: You can then just open with `File-Open` the `pom` file and IntelliJ will ask you if you want to open as a project. You say yes, and click all default settings and open in new window. It should work. Just to mention that IntelliJ is working differently on Windows/Linux even it is the same version. I guess you are on Linux.

Comment: Yes, I am on Linux, I will try next monday, the machine is not at hand now.

Comment: The issue remains the same after import the pom file, it didn't even let me choose options. I would simply ignore this issue, and use `IDEA 2019` instead, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I've addressed this problem by myself.

I've set up my IDEA using my previous setting backup, which therefore lead to the result that there are some legacy settings regarding maven and were imported by IDE.
A reasonable inference is that this is a built-in bug.

Restore the IDEA to default settings help address this problem.

Happy coding